# Error message after install: There Has Been a Critical Error on Your Website” Error

Tags: error, install

This is my second attempt in redeploying CiviCRM. Last time I did not have the command line php.ini and web server same version.

After following the install requirements I get this error message "There Has Been a Critical Error on Your Website” Error". But working with configuration steps no issues.

Does anyone know why, or had this experience?

Last time after setting up the CRM it did not save any cases at all.

I am depending on CiviCRM to help out here and worried it may fail again.

Any admice would help...

Comment: It would help to know more about the setup - WP / Drupal etc. After installing, is there anything in the database ? (I have this problem with my hosting at the moment)